# How to Overlap two images on resizing window

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I have a product page and have a sale image on top left of my product image now when user reduces browser size the sale image goes on top of the product image. I am trying to make them overlap so that the sale image comes over the product image
CSS for sale image:

```
img.sale-img-home-page {
position: relative;
left: 22px;
margin-left: -15px !important;
z-index: 10;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <img src="path_to_sale_img.png" class="sale-img-home-page"> <a href="http://link_for_onclick"><img src="path_to_product_img.png" width="250" height="250" alt=""></a>
```

Take a look at the following image:
[image]

Here is the link to code pen http://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/xEpjLb
Reduce the browser size so that you will see that pre-sale image goes on top

Comment: See the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure that this is what you wanted to achieve, but I will give a try.

JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ofn85fLL/

Snippet:

```css
img.sale-img-home-page {}@media (max-width: 430px) {
  .gozdziki {
    position: relative;
  }
  .sale {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

  <a class="prdocutname" href="http://localhost:8080/First_American/2014-5-silver-peregrine-falcon" title="2014 $5 Silver Peregrine Falcon">Name of product </a>

</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img class='sale' src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/U0Tyh0HWDmwcq7-sKVtjJZhXF8CMHv8MtwvVBJF1lxmGg2frQfTPNdXaaQLaUYpm-rlmnxc=s152" class="sale-img-home-page">
  <a class='gozdziki' href="#">
    <img src="http://www.royaltyfreeimages.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/royalty-free-images-frozen-flowers.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt="">
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change position to `absolute` and adjust the position as you like:

```
img.sale-img-home-page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjVqyJ

Comment: then try to add `.thumbnail { position: relative; }`